# Ruby sqlite3 gem in Ubuntu fails

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I have been playing with Ruby in Ubuntu for a home grown project for fun. I need to require the sqlite3 gem of Ruby. My current ruby version is ruby 2.3.1

Here's what I get whether I try to run the ruby file that has the require 'sqlite3' gem line:

```
warfreak@warfreak-System-Product-Name:~/Documents/projects/MyProject$ ./runner.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)

from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from /home/warfreak/Documents/projects/MyProject/encryptor.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
from /home/warfreak/Documents/projects/MyProject/cryptobreaker.rb:3:in 'require_relative'
from /home/warfreak/Documents/projects/MyProject/cryptobreaker.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
from ./runner.rb:3:in 'require_relative'
from ./runner.rb:3:in '<main>'
```

Any one have ideas how to get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after delving too much into trying to see what's wrong in my ruby installation, I managed to install too many ruby packages but none of them work. Then I stumbled into this site:

`https://makandracards.com/makandra/1334-install-the-sqlite-3-gem-for-ruby-under-ubuntu`

It gave the appropriate ruby gem installation I need with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

This totally fixed that error I had before. I just want to share this knowledge to anyone having trouble with their Ruby gem installations in Ubuntu 16.04 Linux.  ;)